# handle multiple double quotes & apostrophe in json key value in sql

Tags: mysql, sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
metadata 
-----------
{'a': 'jay', 'b': '100', 'c': ""ANAND'S STORE"", 'd': '200'}
```

Having difficulty parsing this in sql

Need to get like this:

```
a       b          c             d
----------------------------------------
jay | 100   |  ANAND'S STORE |  200
```

I have tried `json_extract_path_text(metadata, 'c') as store_name` but throwing error `Error parsing JSON: more than one document in the input`

I am open to solution in mysql or postgresql also.

Comment: Why have you selected the tags `mysql` and `snowflake`, AND `ansi-sql` as there is no ansi-sql support for JSON, and mysql and snowflake are different databases

Comment: i tried this in snowflake but open to answers in mysql that's why. for `ansi-sql`, it was out of context, have removed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Snowflake:

The problem is double double quotes, is how you escape quote inside CSV, but this is JSON, and thus double double quotes do not mean anything, so if we replace the double doubles, with a single double, for this data we are all good.

```
select column1 as a
    ,replace(a, '""','"') as b
    ,parse_json(b) as c
    ,c:a::text as c_a
from values 
('{\'a\': \'jay\', \'b\': \'100\', \'c\': ""ANAND\'S STORE"", \'d\': \'200\'}');
```

gives:

| A | B | C | C_A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| {'a': 'jay', 'b': '100', 'c': ""ANAND'S STORE"", 'd': '200'} | {'a': 'jay', 'b': '100', 'c': "ANAND'S STORE", 'd': '200'} | { "a": "jay", "b": "100", "c": "ANAND'S STORE", "d": "200" } | jay |